# Is there a constant C such that $\|f\|_q<C\|f\|_p $ for all $f\in L^q?$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $1<p<q<\infty$; then is there a constant C such that $\|f\|_q\leq C\|f\|_p$ for all $f\in L^q?$

I have been trying to solve this question for several days. But don't have a clue where to start. Can someone gives me some hint where should I start? Thanks.

Comment: Very minor latex formatting tip: `$\|x\|$` ($\|x\|$) looks marginally better than `$||x||$` ($||x||$) and is the normal way of writing the double bars - the difference is more apparent when you have something taller instead of $x$ inside the expression, like $$\left\|\frac ab\right\|$$

Comment: Suppose you wanted to prove this was false.  Then you would need to find a sequence of functions $f$ such that $\|f\|_q/\|f\|_p \to \infty$.  So you would want the $p$-norm to be small and the $q$-norm to be large.  Since $q > p$, this happens when $f$ has a sharp peak.  You should try out some functions and compute their norms, and see which ones have the largest value of $\|f\|_q/\|f\|_p$.  That is a clue where to start.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes if and only if the $L_p$ spaces are finite-dimensional**, i.e., the underlying measure space contains only finitely many points. Otherwise no. For example,
if $(\Omega,\mu)$ is a probability space then $|\!|f|\!|_p\leq |\!|f|\!|_q$ for $1\leq p\leq q$, so if you had the reverse inequality, you'd get that $L_p(\Omega,\mu)$ is isomorphic to $L_q(\Omega,\mu)$, which is not true for $p\neq q$ when the spaces are infinite-dimensional. The general case (infinite measure, e.g.) also has a negative answer in the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: what if $\Omega$ is a compact set in $R$, does this change anything?

Answer (score 0):

If it would have such a constant then $L^p\subset L^q$ which is of course wrong...

Comment: "of course" :).

Comment: what if only on say [0,1] with Lebesgue measure. Is it still not possible?